# C# memory access optimization that offset large array (Why is this code slow)

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, memory

I'm working on image processing in C#.
I have a problem getting the performance of offset large memory access in C#.
The speed is significantly different from the same size of zero offset memory.
In the case of C ++, the difference was not as great as in C#.

Can you please tell me why my code has this problem ?
Also, are there any solutions ?

#### Source

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var width = 8000;
            var height = 8000;

            // var data = new Vector4[height * width]; <- similar problem occur
            var data = (Vector4*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * width * sizeof(Vector4));
            var data2 = (Vector4*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * width * sizeof(Vector4));

            // MATRIX
            float m11 = .7297023F, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m14 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = .6109577F,
                m23 = 0, m24 = 0, m31 = 0, m33 = .597218F, m32 = 0, m34 = 0, m41 = 0, m42 = 0,
                m43 = 0, m44 = 1F, m51 = .105F, m52 = .145F, m53 = .155F, m54 = 0;

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
            {
                var offset = width * y;
                for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
                {
                    // Slow ( 600ms )
                    ref var sData = ref data[offset + x];
                    ref var dData = ref data2[offset + x];

                    // Fast ( 200ms )
                    // ref var sData = ref data[x];
                    // ref var dData = ref data2[x];

                    float b = sData.X;
                    float g = sData.Y;
                    float r = sData.Z;
                    float a = sData.W;

                    dData.X = (b * m11) + (g * m21) + (r * m31) + (a * m41) + m51;
                    dData.Y = (b * m12) + (g * m22) + (r * m32) + (a * m42) + m52;
                    dData.Z = (b * m13) + (g * m23) + (r * m33) + (a * m43) + m53;
                    dData.W = (b * m14) + (g * m24) + (r * m34) + (a * m44) + m54;
                }
            }

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)data);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)data2);
        }
    }
}
```

#### When using managed array pointer

```cs
var array1 = new Vector4[width * height];
var array2 = new Vector4[width * height];
fixed (Vector4* data = &array1[0])
fixed (Vector4* data2 = &array2[0])
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            // Slow ( 600ms )
            ref var sData = ref data[width * y + x];
            ref var dData = ref data2[width * y + x];
```

#### Offsetting the pointer in the outer loop

（A little improvement）

```cs
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    var offsetData1 = data + width * y;
    var offsetData2 = data2 + width * y;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        // Slow ( 470ms )
        ref var sData = ref offsetData1[x];
        ref var dData = ref offsetData2[x];
```

#### C++ ver

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct Vector4 {
    float X = 0;
    float Y = 0;
    float Z = 0;
    float W = 0;
};

int main()
{
    long width = 8000;
    long height = 8000;

    auto buffer = new Vector4[width * height];
    auto buffer2 = new Vector4[width * height];

    // MATRIX
    float m11 = .7297023F, m12 = 0, m13 = 0, m14 = 0, m21 = 0, m22 = .6109577F,
        m23 = 0, m24 = 0, m31 = 0, m33 = .597218F, m32 = 0, m34 = 0, m41 = 0, m42 = 0,
        m43 = 0, m44 = 1, m51 = .105F, m52 = .145F, m53 = .155F, m54 = 0;

    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point  start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        int offset = width * y;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            Vector4& sData = buffer[offset + x];
            Vector4& dData = buffer2[offset + x];

            float b = sData.X;
            float g = sData.Y;
            float r = sData.Z;
            float a = sData.W;
            dData.X = (b * m11) + (g * m21) + (r * m31) + (a * m41) + m51;
            dData.Y = (b * m12) + (g * m22) + (r * m32) + (a * m42) + m52;
            dData.Z = (b * m13) + (g * m23) + (r * m33) + (a * m43) + m53;
            dData.W = (b * m14) + (g * m24) + (r * m34) + (a * m44) + m54;
        }
    }

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    double elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << elapsed << "\n";

    delete[] buffer;
    delete[] buffer2;
}
```

### Benchmarks

| Lang | description | time (ms) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C# | Zero offset pointer | 600ms |
| C# | Offset pointer | 200ms |
| C++ | Zero offset pointer | 190ms |
| C++ | Offset pointer | 260ms |
| C# | Offsetting the pointer in the outer loop | 370ms |
| C# | Managed array pointer with offset | 990ms |

### Other info

[IL in SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| CPU | Intel Core i7-6700k |
| Memory | DDR4 16GB |
| OS | Windows 10 20H2 |
| Runtime | .NET 5 |
| Lang ver | C# 9 |
| Platform | X64 |

Comment: looks like you tried to use a managed array. Did you also try using a pointer to the managed array? I would also try offsetting the pointer in the outer loop, i.e. `var dataOffset = data + width * y`

Comment: Also, your "fast" c# example could be explained by accessing the same values every time, i.e. data will always be from registers or L1 cache. It would be useful to have performance numbers from the c++ implementation for comparison (and fix it so the implementations actually does the same thing, and ensure the c++ code does not use SIMD or other fancy optimizations not available in .Net).

Comment: Have you compared against a `stackalloc` array? Do you know if your C++ example is cheating due to undefined behaviour accessing an uninitialised `buffer`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman stackalloc 8000*8000*4*4 will crash with default stack sizes. Also the allocation is not measured, so no cheating here.